# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/XXX.XXXXX/Downloads' when interacting with Pandas and GUI

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, permission-denied, pysimplegui

I am trying to hook up a PySimpleGUI to my CSV formatter function from another .py file in the same directory. I am trying to feed it the input file and an output file. The program works if I manually input the output destination, but I get PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/XXX.XXXXX/Downloads' if I use the GUI interface. I want the output file to be whatever is selected in the GUI.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from SBOE_Formatter import boe_formatter


def select_target_client(client_pick):
    # <---Client Picker menu--->
    sg.theme("DarkTeal10")

    layout = [[sg.T("Client picker")],
              [sg.T(""), sg.Combo(client_pick["CLIENTS"]["c1"].split("|"), size=(30, 5),
                                  default_value=client_pick["CLIENTS"]["client default"], s=1, key="-SET_CLIENT-")],
              [sg.B("Save client selection", s=20)]]

    window = sg.Window("Client selector", layout, modal=True, size=(300, 100))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Save client selection":
            client_pick["CLIENTS"]["c2"] = values["-SET_CLIENT-"]

            sg.popup_no_titlebar("Client selection saved")
            break
    window.close()


def main_window():
    # <---Main Window--->
    sg.theme("DarkTeal10")

    layout = [[sg.T("Eligibility File:", s=15, justification="r"), sg.I(key="-EF_IN-"), sg.FileBrowse()],
              [sg.T("User List File:", s=15, justification="r"), sg.I(key="-UL_IN-"), sg.FileBrowse()],
              [sg.T("Target Location:", s=15, justification="r"), sg.I(key="-OUT-"), sg.FolderBrowse()],
              [sg.B("Format EF only", s=16), sg.B("Merge files", s=16), sg.B("Select client type", s=16)]]

    window = sg.Window("Eligibility/User-List Merger", layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == "Select client type":
            select_target_client(client_list)
        if event == "Format EF only":
            boe_formatter(values["-EF_IN-"], values["-OUT-"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_path = str(Path.cwd())
    client_list = sg.UserSettings(
        path=client_path, filename="Clients_List.ini", use_config_file=True, convert_bools_and_none=True
    )
    main_window()
```

I have looked all around, and some solutions I see are to run this from the command prompt as an administrator, but that does not help me as I am looking to package the final system up for co-workers to quickly edit files, and they wont know how to run it in the command prompt.

Comment: I don't see a solution other than that, since you can't run a python script on itself as admin, and that is a requirement for what you want

Comment: Is there a way to set it to automatically go to a users download folder? That worked when i set the path to my own downloads, but how would i go about making that automated to each unique user?